# iOS PDF Form Fields

Tags: iphone, pdf

I am using CGPDF to parse a PDF for an iPhone application. I can get as far as obtaining the dictionary object but for the life of me I cant seem to locate the form fields in the PDF.

How can I get a list of the text fields in a PDF Document?

After I find the text fields, how can i know the location for each?

example: text field "First Name" is on page one at coordinate:(20,30) with size:(100,25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've succeeded in getting to the Page dictionary, then try and check out the 'Annots' Array.  The Array should contain a Dictionary entry for each Text field in the document.  Each Dictionary entry should contain several entries such as 'rect' (among others) that will contain the coordinates of the field on the page.

If you have acrobat pro, a great way to browse the PDF document structure is to use 'Preflight' (Under the advanced menu). Once you have preflight running click on the 'options' button in the top right of the dialog and click on 'browse internal PDF structure' you can poke around here to see how your PDF is laid out.

You can also find additional info on the 'Annots' Array entry in the [Adobe PDF Reference, Sixth Edition, version 1.7](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf.html) , section 8.4.1 "Annotation Dictionaries".

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Annot array does not contain textfields rather it contain annotation objects.

Comment: From the specification:  "As a convenience, when a field has only a single associated widget annotation, the contents of the field dictionary and the annotation dictionary (Section 8.4.1, “An- notation Dictionaries”) may be merged into a single dictionary containing entries that pertain to both a field and an annotation. (This presents no ambiguity, since the contents of the two kinds of dictionaries do not conflict.)"